# How can I configure my 2 VM's to communicate with each other via VMware WS, but not connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, vmware, network-adapter

I have 2 windows 10 VM's set up on VMWare Workstation, both have been set to "Host Only" in adapter settings, however they cannot connect to each other or my host device. Am I missing something?

Schema:
Host: 10.122.2.151
VM1: 10.122.2.7 - Host only
VM2: 10.122.2.8 - Host only

Subnet Mask for all is 255.255.255.0

I do not have WS Pro, or access to Virtual Network Editor.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried disabling firewalls all around?

Comment: Not yet but I will try now and let you know the result when I can.

Comment: @harrymc Disabling firewalls on both VM's worked :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that of firewalls blocking the connections.

Disabling firewalls on both VMs worked for the poster.

This being a "Host Only" connection that's not exposed to the internet,
there is no real reason for keeping these firewalls.

Comment: Thank you for your help Harry. Is there no way around this? As I'm simulating for a real-world solution which will have a firewall in place, not having the firewall on the VM's may invalidate any testing I do.

Comment: You will have to add selective rules to the firewalls that let through the communications that are required, instead of disabling them totally.

Comment: Do you know which firewall rules specifically block connections between the two?

Comment: By default, almost every outside connection is blocked. You need to authorize the communications by either port, protocol or even an executable. See for example [How to Create Advanced Firewall Rules in the Windows Firewall](https://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/), but there are lots of other articles to be found.